# VB.NET and bytes

Tags: vb.net, byte

I'm a little confused as to bytes.
I can open a file in a hex editor and know that each 2 digits is a byte, they are 8 digits in binary correct?
How are they stored in arrays in [VB.NET](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_.NET)?
So if I have

`Dim xx() as byte =`

What would I put after the equals? The hex digits from the hex editor?

(This is just a program I'm not going to save, basically I don't want to open files to get etc. I want to put in the bytes in the code.)

---

Thanks everyone for your answers (on new years eve too :) )

Comment: I love reading these innocent questions, they conjure some fun childhood memories :)

Comment: Maybe because, if these comments are not innocent, then they're scary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to write the bytes as a hexadecimal numbers, like this:

```
Dim xx() As Byte = { &H43, &h44, &h4C }
```

You can also write bytes as regular decimal numbers, like this:

```
Dim xx() As Byte = { 67, 68, 76 }
```

Comment: I think it is terminating at the first zero in your array.

Comment: The `&H0` bytes translate to `\0` (null) characters.  MsgBox calls an API function which takes a null-terminated string, so the only byte that MsgBox sees is `&H17`, which is  non-printable character and shows up as a box.  In general, you should avoid strings with nulls in them; they will behave unexpectedly.

Comment: It just isn't a string in any kind of conventional encoding.  GIGO.

Comment: If you want to print a content of a byte array as a sequence of hex numbers, one per byte (as hex editor shows it), use `BitConverter.ToString()`. When you use `Encoding.ASCII.GetString()`, you get a string consisting of characters, each of which has ASCII code corresponding to one byte.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax for hex values in VB uses &H ie

```
    Dim xx() As Byte = {&HAB, &H2C, &HFF }
```

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s9cz43ek.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Be careful not to confuse bytes for characters.  In VB.NET, a character often takes up several bytes.

Answer (score 0):

A byte is represented in binary as eight bits.  Binary is base two, so with eight bits you can store a maximum of 256 values.  When you use a hex editor to view a byte, you see two digits because the hex values are in base sixteen.  To show 256 values requires two hex digits (maximum values per hex digit = sixteen, 256 = 16 x 16).  As mentioned above, the syntax for representing a hex value is &H--, where -- is hex and &H identifies the value as hex.  If you're familiar with C/C++, this was represented as 0x--.

As noted, a character is not necessarily a byte.  The ASCII characters occupy one byte on some systems (DOS, etc.), but as Windows implements Unicode, a character can be a multibyte value.  A good example of this would be a Kanji (Japanese) character/glyph.

Happy coding,

Scott